# Throttle in React

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, events, mouseevent

Surprisingly for me, this following code, meant to throttle `mousemove`  within my React Component class doesnt work as expected, the state is always reported true & mousemove continues to be fired continuously. I do not understand why that is.

```
class SVGParent extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
      super( props );
        ...
        this.dispatchMouseMoveThrottle = this.dispatchMouseMoveThrottle.bind( this );
    }
    ...
    dispatchMouseMoveThrottle( a ){
        let state = true;
        let dispatchMouseMove = this.props.dispatchMouseMove;
        return( function( e ){
            e.persist(); // this excludes from React's synthetic event system
            setTimeout( function(){
                state = true;
            }, 5000);
            if( state === true ){
                state = false;
                return( dispatchMouseMove( abc ));
            }
        });
    }
    render(){
        ...
        return(
            <svg
                ...
                mousemove = {this.dispatchMouseMoveThrottle( a )}
            </svg>
        );
}
```

Comment: can you show how exactly you call `dispatchMouseMoveThrottle()`?

Comment: @GProst apologies for the delay, updated the answer with the structure of the class & how mousemove is called. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I presume, the problem is that when `mousemove` event triggers it doesn't call the function which returned by `dispatchMouseMoveThrottle(a)`. Instead it calls `dispatchMouseMoveThrottle(a)` every time it triggers. So that's why `state` variable is always `true`.

I think you better keep `state` variable as a global in your component. Or may be you can just try use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) `debounce` or `throttle` methods, which may be helpful.

Comment: thanks, I suspect what you are saying is correct. However, Im not keen on using lodash, it would be awesome to resolve this for my own understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by declaring a `global` variable within the module & then reading / modifying it within the component.

Code:

```
let mouseMoveState = true;
const changeMouseMoveState = function( changeTo ){
    mouseMoveState = changeTo;
};

class SVGParent extends React.Component{
 ...
    dispatchMouseMoveThrottle( a, b ){
        let dispatchMouseMove = this.props.dispatchMouseMove;
        return( function( e ){
            if( a.mouseDownState === true ){
                e.persist(); // this excludes from React's synthetic event system
                if( mouseMoveState === true ){
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        changeMouseMoveState( true );
                    }, 500 );
                    changeMouseMoveState( false );
                    return( dispatchMouseMove( a, b ));
                }

            }
        });
    }
```